# Can you tell me what is wrong with my Entity Framework Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to select an entity of type Member with this code in C#. I was watching a video tutorial and they do it just the same, but it doesn't work for me.

```
        Member member = new Member();
        var query =  from m in db.Members  where Member.MemberID == textBox1.Text 
        select m;     
        var currentMember =  query.FirstOrDefault();
        string CurrentID = M.MemberID;
```

There are no exceptions or stuff, but I get all of the currentMember's properties are null.
Any ideas to get the expected result?

Comment: Do you have any Members in the database? Or is there a Member in the Database that equals the name provided in the textbox?

Comment: are u getting back value from `textBox1.Text` and that needs to be int? are u getting any exception?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a correct value from the textbox. I don't get any exceptions. The Id is of type varchar.

Comment: and did u check database? do u havea  record for that member?

Comment: Yes, it is my own database. I already made sure it exists.

Comment: Is that query correct? Shouldn't it be `m.MemberID == textBox1.Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be mixing up your variables a little bit here. Let's try to clean this code up:

```
var memberQuery = from m in db.Members
                  where m.MemberID == textBox1.Text
                     // ^ you need to reference the MemberID by the query
                     //   variable (m) not the class name (Member).
                  select m;

var member = memberQuery.SingleOrDefault();
                      // ^ when you only expect zero or one records from the
                      //   database, use SingleOrDefault instead of
                      //   FirstOrDefault, because it will throw an exception
                      //   when more than one record is returned.

if (member != null)
 // ^ always check to make sure that the database returned a value before trying
 //   to access any fields on the object.
{
    string currentId = member.MemberID;
}
else
{
    // a member with the given ID doesn't exist in the database
}
```

Comment: I added some comments to guide you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `where Member.MemberID == textBox1.Text`

It should have been `where m.MemberID == textBox1.Text`

Why are you creating a member? `Member member = new Member();`

Just get the Member from the query and get the id from it.